# Cannot change the simulated location of Android Studio emulator from its Extended Controls - Google map isn't showing in the Extended Controls window

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator, manjaro

My Android Studio emulator was working fine. Ever since just a couple days I'm unable to change the simulated location from the extended controls window as the Google map displayed in there doesn't show up.

[image]

As shown in the picture above, the map doesn't show up. When I first open the Extended Controls window a white area is displayed in its place for a second and then it disappears as nothing is there. I'm using the Google Play system image.
I've tried closing and reopening the emulator, cold-booting the emulator, creating a new emulator with a different system image (Android API level), deleting the emulator from the SDK manager, and redownloading it. My SDK & Android Studio IDE are up-to-date.
I'm running Manjaro Linux with the latest updates installed.
The problem is that it was working just fine and then suddenly I was no longer able to change the simulated location. My emulators are running fine and the Google Maps app is running fine inside the emulator.
Can someone guide me to where the problem can be or what can I do?

Comment: I too experience this on Pop_OS! 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an issue on Google IssueTracker and they acknowledged the bug and said that they have a fix coming out soon.

My issue link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/242438611